# how to show only date?

Tags: asp.net

I have a column in the data table called CurrentDate as datatype string (12/2/1983).

When I am displaying on the screen this is showing as 12/2/1983 12:00:00AM.

I am not sure why I am getting timestamp here?

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Do you want the SQL code or the ASP.net code? how is it being displayed?

Comment: No offense kumar, but after 96 questions you should try and get better at asking them...for example, **where** are you displaying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are binding this from a datasource, like a SQL Data Source, you can use CONVERT in your query:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),nameOfColumn,101) AS Date
```

If you need to do this in C#, try the ToShortDateString() method:

```
string date = myDate.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# if you convert it to a `DateTime` object:

```
DateTime.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using data binding to a gridview, formview, or other formatable data source? If so you can simply use the "d" format flag, like below:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="MyDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="My Date" />
```

Comment: Agreed: and similarly in WinForms with DataBinding use Binding.FormatString = "{0:d}".

Answer (score 0):

An example of its usage within the context of setting a label would be:

```
MyLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("A FORMATTING STRING HERE);
```

Two very useful MSFT posts I use are:  ["Standard DateTime formatting strings"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)  and ["Custom date time formatting strings"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)